# How to stop the animation of my object at a set distance?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a code where my object starts animation at a click and ends when the mouse is hovered over the object, but I'm struggling to implement how to stop it at a certain distance ie animation of object stops after 200px distance. I've tried doing experiments with setIntervals and such in my code, but none went the way I wanted it to. In the end, I've ended up deleting it back to this original code below:

```js
//      MOTION VARIABLES
const block = document.querySelector('.red');
const center = {
  x: parseFloat(getComputedStyle(block).left), 
  y: parseFloat(getComputedStyle(block).top),
};
let newX = 0.0;
let newY = 0.0; 
let motionSway = 0.02;
let naturalSway = 0.1;
let animatedValue = 0.0;
let animationId = null;


function startAnimation(){
  
// MOTION MODIFICATION
  newX = center.x + animatedValue;
  newY = center.y + (25/*size of amp*/ * Math.sin(motionSway * animatedValue /*the time it takes*/)) + naturalSway;
  
  block.style.left = `${newX}px`;
  block.style.top = `${newY}px`;
  
  animatedValue++;
  
  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(startAnimation);//recursion
 
}



window.addEventListener('click', () => {
      startAnimation();
});

window.addEventListener("mouseover", () =>{
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationId);
});
```

```css
.red{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="red"></div>
```

*NOTE*

I adjusted the objects, classname etc from my original code in attempt for readibility, but it ended up making the JS not responsive. (The JS code works as is in my original but it lags quite a bit with all the other functions etc <- not sure if this is due to my own laptop not being able to handle all the animation going or what..) It's suppose to move in an up and down motion but please let me know if I should change the snippet to what I have in my original code!

If anyone knows a way to implement stopping at a set distance with the code I have it would be great! :)

Thank  you!

Comment: I'm having trouble running your code, but you should consider just adding `Math.sqrt( x*x + y*y )` to a counter or something, then stop after the counter hits the desired number. When it comes to swaying you could also just use, say, a `sin` wave (`Math.sin( Math.PI * 2 * timePassed / duration )`, for example), instesd of computing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to resolve your problem in the following way as per your requirement. Please check the same.

I have added the animation through CSS and handing it through Javascript.
When clicked anywhere on the document, the animation starts playing. And when hovered over the object, the animation will pause and if clicked again, it will run. Also, at a distance of 200px, it will pause by itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Animation</title>
    <style>      
      .red{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        animation: move 5s forwards;  
      }

      /* Need to add this animation css on the div element */
      @keyframes move{
        0%{
          transform:  translateX(0);
        }
        100%{
          transform: translateX(200px);
        }
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="red"></div>

   <script>
    const block = document.querySelector('.red');

    /* Default state of animation will be 'paused' */
    block.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';

    /* If clicked anywhere on the event, it will run aur pause the animation */
    window.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        const running = block.style.animationPlayState || 'running';
        block.style.animationPlayState = running === 'running' ? 'paused' : 'running';
    });

    /* If mouse is hovered hover the object, this will pause the animation */
    block.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
      if(block.style.animationPlayState === 'running') block.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';

    });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not 'as per requirement', the requirement was kind of helping fix the javascript code. Don't get me wrong, but the OP is asking how to measure the distance of the block travelled more than how to do this in CSS.

Comment: Ok, I got you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to stop the animation when the x position of the object is at say 200px, you can do something like this:

```
if(newX <= 200){
     newX = center.x + animatedValue;
     block.style.left = `${newX}px`;
     animatedValue++;
     animationId = requestAnimationFrame(startAnimation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if it's confusing, another reason why I set it the way I did in the snippet was because I was unsure how add SCSS to the styling portion of the code.

Perhaps I could just post my codepen here:

https://codepen.io/ko-d14/pen/poeKOga

I'm still in the process of learning how JS works, so I apologize in advance if the code isn't clean.

```js
//      MOTION VARIABLES
const candle1 = document.querySelector('.container');
const center = {
  x: parseFloat(getComputedStyle(candle1).left), 
  y: parseFloat(getComputedStyle(candle1).top),
};
let newX = 0.0;
let newY = 0.0; 
let motionSway = 0.02;
let naturalSway = 0.1;
let animatedValue = 0.0;
let animationId = null;


function startAnimation(){
  
// MOTION MODIFICATION
  newX = center.x + animatedValue;
  newY = center.y + (25/*size of amp*/ * Math.sin(motionSway * animatedValue /*the time it takes*/)) + naturalSway;
  
  candle1.style.left = `${newX}px`;
  candle1.style.top = `${newY}px`;
  
  animatedValue++;
  
  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(startAnimation);//recursion
 
}



window.addEventListener('click', () => {
      startAnimation();
});

window.addEventListener("mouseover", () =>{
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationId);
});


// makes the eye follow mouse
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {eyeball(e.pageX, e.pageY);});
function eyeball(targetX, targetY) {
  const eye = document.querySelectorAll('.eye');
  eye.forEach(function(eye){
    let x = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().left) + (eye.clientWidth / 2);
    let y = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().top) + (eye.clientHeight / 2);
    
    let radian = Math.atan2(targetX - x, targetY - y);
    let transformX = Math.round(Math.sin(radian) * 100);
    let transformY = Math.round(Math.cos(radian) * 100);
    eye.style.transform = "translate("+transformX+"%, "+transformY+ "%)";
  });
} 

$('.candle-fire-container').fadeOut(15000);
```

```css
$bg: #0f092e;
$candle-width: 60px;

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: $bg;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
// EYE

.eye-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
 }


@keyframes blink{
  to{
    transform: translateY(-99%);
    
  }
}
.eyeball{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  overflow: hidden;
 
  &:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    @extend .eyeball;
  background: $bg !important;
    animation: blink 6s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
    transition-delay: 15s;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    z-index: 3;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
  }
}
.pupil{
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
 width: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  border: 10px solid purple;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

// CANDLE
.container { // what will be used for eyes to follow
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  //box-shadow: 0 0 3px #3b3657;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 35px;
    z-index: 10;
}

@keyframes float{
  35%{
    transform: scale(1.5) translate(0, -10%);
  }  
  50%{
    transform: scale(1) translate(0, -20%);
  }
  75%{
    transform: scale(1.2) translate(0, -30%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1) translate( -5%, 0);
  }
}
.candle-fire-container {
  position: relative;
opacity: 0.7;

  .candle-fire {
    position: absolute;
    top: -90px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;

    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid salmon;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px 10px;
animation: float 5s ease alternate infinite; 
    
    
    &:after {
      //bottomhalf
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 30px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: salmon;
      top: 35px;
      left: -15px;
      box-shadow: 0 6px 60px 25px salmon;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  }
}

.candle-fire-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid yellow;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px 19px;
  z-index: 3;
  animation: float 5s ease alternate infinite; 

  &:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 11px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: yellow;
    top: 25px;
    left: -5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px 10px yellow;
  }
}

.candle-wick {
  position: relative;
  width: 2px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #452d2b;
  top: -10px;
  left: 30px;
}

.candle-stick {
  background: #ededed;
  height: 200px;
  width: $candle-width;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px lightGray;

  &:after {
    //shadow
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: lightGray;
    height: inherit;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: inherit;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 20px;
  }
}

.candle-reflection {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 7px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  left: -13px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="eye-container">
  <div class="eyelids eyelid-left"></div>
  <div class="eyelids eyelid-right"></div>
    <div class=" eyeball left-eye">
      <div class=" eye pupil left-pupil"></div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="eyeball right-eye">
      <div class="eye pupil right-pupil"></div>
    </div>
    </section>

  
 

  <section class="container">
    <div class="candle-fire-container">
      <div class="candle-fire"></div>
      <div class="candle-fire-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="candle-wick"></div>
    <div class="candle-wax"></div>

    <div class="candle-stick"></div>
    <div class="candle-reflection"></div>

  </section>
```

Comment: Please ignore the snippet above. I was unable to post the link to my codepen without adding the code in Stack, but again I am unsure as to how to add SCSS here so the snippet results are very off...